# Postgres full text search doesn't search special words (Proper nouns)

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 9.5

Full text search works properly in test environment, but has problems in production: it can't find anything, when i'm querieng specific words, like names or titles of cities. Problems only with russian language. I guess, something wrong with some config settings or encoding settings or so.

I'm storing information in two languages: english and russian.

This is the table created in order to use full text search:

```
CREATE TABLE public.tsv
(
  name character varying NOT NULL,
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  tsv tsvector NOT NULL,
  image boolean DEFAULT false,
  source uuid,
  "user" uuid,
  CONSTRAINT tsv_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT source FOREIGN KEY (source)
      REFERENCES public.source (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.tsv
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

This is an example of queries i'm using for search:

```
select id, name, image, type from tsv where tsv @@ to_tsquery('russian', 'кант') limit 18
```

It searchs for the person name "кант" (russian word - from the Immanuel Kant - the philosopher)
This query properly returns this row in test environment:

```
"Кант – Пол Стретерн";
"2779061c-3b58-4684-890c-cc24e8f5cdc0";
"'1724–1804 –':7 '«долга»':42 '«категорическ':44 'Аристотел':18 'Имману':5 'Кант':1A,6,24,46 'Платон':16 'Пол':3A 'Стрем':19 'Стретерн':4A 'Философ':41 'границ':21 'действительн':33 'императива»':45 'классическ':10 'крупн':13 'легкост':48 'лиш':35 'мыслител':14 'немецк':9 'определ':20 'опрокидыва':49 'основоположник':8 'позна':32 'познан':23 'получ':36 'представлен':40 'результат':54 'сам':12 'совершен':59 'спекулятивн':51 'стал':58 'субъективн':39 'теор':52 'указа':25 'философ':11,55 'человек':29 'человеческ':22 '–':2A";
"2779061c-3b58-4684-890c-cc24e8f5cdc0"
```

But exactly the same query can't find exactly the same row in production. Hovewer, if i'm searching for ordinary words (not names or titles of cities etc), then it searchs properly.

This is the SQL pane from production database:

```
CREATE DATABASE production_v2
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

This is from test one:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_database
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

The test database located on my mac, the production is located on VPS (Debian)

Comment: @Renzo, not sure yet, but it looks like you right. How did you solved it?

Comment: My problem was with UTF-8 strings contaning italian accented characters. This is due to the differences about the management of uppercase and lowercase characters by Mac and Linux (in my case, the Mac did incorrectly changed the case when the letter is accented). Maybe the problem is similar for russian upper/lowercase letters. Perhaps you could try to do uppercase or lowercase conversion before passing the text to `to_tsquery`.

Comment: Found the old mail: someone suggested me to pass from UTF-8 encoding to ISO8859 encoding. I did'nt used this solution, since the deployment server was a Linux server, and in Linux the uppercase/lowercase functions do the correct conversion.

Comment: it will be hard to convert all of the stored data `to_tsquery` again. I'll try to find way to make Debian treat it properly

Comment: Probably this is the best strategy.

Comment: Since you say that it works on your test system, but not on production, I'd search for differences. How is `default_text_search_config` set on both systems? What is the content of `tsv` for the row that should match on the production system?

Comment: @Renzo was right: problem is in initial indexation. For some reason, `tsv` column contains strings with uppercase, which breakes things apart. The only solution for existing data - is reindexation with forced lowercase. For further data i'll need iether to submit it lowercased or find out wth debian dosn't understand it properly. I've chosen Postgres funcion `lower('string')`, because any other investigations will take too much time